# Where is the Sieve of Eratosthenes used today?

Tags: algorithm, sieve-of-eratosthenes

I'm doing a research paper on the topic and while I find a lot of examples and discussion about *how* the algorithm works/should be implemented, I can't find anything on *where* it's actually used.

Is there any field in which the algorithm is used today? Or do people just implement it for "shits 'n giggles" (it's fairly simple, so that would make some sense)?

I know that large prime numbers are important in the field of encryption, but I doubt the sieve is used to find/generate those primes. Also, the huge amount of memory needed to find large primes makes it inefficient for those, too.

So is the algorithm, in any form, used anywhere today?

Comment: Probably people use it for empirical studies of how primes are distributed, a topic of great interest to analytic number theorists (so I'm told).

Comment: `I know that large prime numbers are important in the field of encryption, but I doubt the sieve is used to find/generate those primes.` - actually, it is used to HELP with that: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_primes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the Wikipedia article on the subject](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes), that particular sieve is still a very efficient method for producing the full list of primes whose value is less than a few millions. Also, the [general idea of a sieve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_theory) is used in several other, more powerful algorithms, such as the [General number field sieve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_number_field_sieve) for factoring large integers.

Comment: I think it's even one of the most efficient approaches for primes up to a few billions if http://www.spoj.com/ranks/KPRIMES2/ is anything to go by :)  My SoE implementation ranks within factor 2 of the top solution and I'm sure it's not as optimized as possible.

Comment: @NiklasB. are all those solutions in the table using the sieve? Or where you free to use whatever algorithm you wanted?

Comment: @Lukas you can use whatever you want,  and I'm sure some people used sieve of attkin, but from what I've read it's slower than SoE for this kind of scale

Answer (score 1):

You can view a prime sieve as an application of *dynamic programming* to small complete *prime number* enumeration and testing.  So your question is really "what do we need prime numbers for?".  They are a fundamental part of number theory.  As one example encoding an integer into its prime factorization has all sorts of useful properties and higher-level utility.  By adding backtracking to a sieve we can perform this factorization very quickly.

Comment: I don't understand how the sieve is an application of dynamic programming. Can you please detail?

Comment: @IVlad: Sure. The function we want is `P: int -> bool`, for each integer whether it is prime.  You can view the sieve (the array) as a memoization of that function.  We then eagerly evaluate it bottom-up.